# hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerhub

```
"hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.minus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/var/lib/jenkins] Possible solutions: find(), image(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), find(groovy.lang.Closure), any(), build(java.lang.String)"
```

Below is my script, Why I am getting above error? please help me to solve this error

```
node{
    stage('Login to server') {
        sshagent(['ssh-login']) {
            sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  Server_name'
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'dockerhubpwd', variable: 'docker-pwd')]) {
                sh "docker -u my_username -p ${docker-pwd}"
            }

        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you replace the last sh comand into

```
sh "docker -u my_username -p ${env.'docker-pwd'}"
```

Or every occurence of the `docker-pwd` variable gets renamed to dockerPwd (or whatever value without a dash)